# A valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: reactjs

Странная реакция на следующий код:

```
const IssueRow = (props) => {
    console.log(props.issue.title);
        <tr>
            <td>{props.issue.id}</td>
            <td>{props.issue.status}</td>
            <td>{props.issue.owner}</td>
            <td>{props.issue.created.toDateString()}</td>
            <td>{props.issue.effort}</td>
            <td>{props.issue.completionDate ? issue.completionDate.toDateString() : ''}</td>
            <td>{props.issue.title}</td>
        </tr>
}
function IssueTable(props) {
    const issueRows = props.issues.map(issue =><IssueRow key={issue.id} issue={issue} />);
    return (
        <table className="bordered-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Owner</th>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>Effort</th>
                    <th>Completion date</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{issueRows}</tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

Почему возникает проблема? Делаю по учебнику, код проверен.

> **Warning**: IssueRow(...): A valid React element (or null) must be
>   returned.

Comment: IssueRow ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 0):

проблема была в неправильном синтаксисе arrow function: вместо

```
const Issue Row = (props ) => {}
```

надо было написать:

```
const IssueRow = (props) => (
        console.log(props.issue.title);
            <tr>
                ...
            </tr>
    )
```

Comment: Этот код выдаст синтаксическую ошибку. Правильнее просто return вставить

Answer (score 0):

Нужно писать либо так:

```
const IssueRow = (props) => {
    console.log(/* ... */);
    return <tr> // ← явный вызов return
        // ...
    </tr>;
};
```

либо так:

```
const IssueRow = (props) => (
    console.log(/* ... */), // ← запятая
    <tr>
        // ...
    </tr>
);
```

А раз уж у нас всё равно babel, то можно уменьшить повторения:

```
const IssueRow = ({ issue }) => {
    console.log(issue.title);
    return <tr>
        <td>{issue.id}</td>
        <td>{issue.status}</td>
        <td>{issue.owner}</td>
        <td>{issue.created.toDateString()}</td>
        <td>{issue.effort}</td>
        <td>{issue.completionDate ? issue.completionDate.toDateString() : ''}</td>
        <td>{issue.title}</td>
    </tr>;
};
```

P.S. Кстати, в предпоследнем `<td>` у вас ошибка — переменная `issue` не определена.